# i am not able to pass the html textbox values to webservice using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-services

i am not able to pass the html textbox values to webservice using jquery
my jquery is working fine for empty userName and password but it is not working if i add the ajax part. please help me in this issue
my html script

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" >
        $(function () {
            $("#ButtonLogin").click(function () {
                var username = $("#TextUN").val();
                var password = $("#TextP").val();
                if (username == "") { alert("fill  the username !"); return; }
                if (password == "") { alert("fill  the password !"); return; }

                var str = "{'userName':'" + username + "', 'password': '" + password + "'}";



                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "http://localhost:4522/AdWebService.asmx/CheckUser",
                    contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: str,
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: function (res) {
                        try {

                            var jsondata = res.d;
                            if (jsondata == "true") {
                                window.location("http://localhost:5273/");
                            }
                            else  {
                                alert("failure")
                            }
                        }
                        catch (e) {
                            alert(e.ToString());
                        }
                    },
                    failure: function (err) {
                        alert(err)
                    }

                });




            });

        });

    </script>
```

my web service method:

```
        [WebMethod]
        public string CheckUser(string un,string pass)
        {
            UserAds u = new UserAds();
            u.UserName = un;
            u.Password = pass;
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return js.Serialize(udao.CheckUser(u));          

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass correct parameters. As you have defined `un` and `pass` as parameter to web service method, you need to use them.

*Use*

```
var str = "{'un':'" + username + "', 'pass': '" + password + "'}";
```

Also you can use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
var str = JSON.stringify({
    un: username,
    pass: password
});
```

Comment: i tried both of them still it is not working.i kept an alertbox after "var jsondata = res.d;" this statement .the message is showing as undefined.

Comment: @KunaKalinga, Declare you WebMethod as static like `public static string`

Answer (score 0):

The better solution would be to not create a string manually for the data to be posted to your service. Instead use the "serialize" function available in jQuery. You can use something like this:

```
var data = $('form').serialize();
```

Thereafter you can pass this data in your ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

var username = $("#TextUN").val();

try

var username = $("#TextUN").text();

Answer (score 0):

Check TextP in you html code.

Else try this syntaxe :

```
var str = '{"userName":"' + username + '", "password": "' + password + '"}';
```